# Jenkins fails to find SureFire Reports

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins Version : **2.176.2**

Executing Selenium tests via Jenkins : Ecplsie+mvn+Jenkins

**Selenium Workspace Folder** : C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\ACA

**The actual location of the testng-results.xml:** C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\ACA\target\surefire-reports\testng-results.xml

**Jenkins Insatlled / Home Directory:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins

**Building in workspace** C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ACATestAutomationJob

**Executing Maven:**  -B -f C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\ACA\pom.xml clean install

**TestNG Reports Processing:** START

Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml

Did not find any matching files.

How do i make jenkins locate this testng-results.xml?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

1. Look into [Jenkins Console Output](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+Console+Output+Plugin), it should report where the build is running (so called [WORKSPACE](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins)) and where [TestNG Results Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) attempts to locate the results file:

   [image]
2. The path to the TestNG results file must be relative to the WORKSPACE and have the syntax of [Ant FileSet](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

If you're uncertain regarding how to properly build the path to the test artifacts - post the full paths to WORKSPACE and the `testng-results.xml` / `emailable-report.html` and we will help you to come up with the correct definitions.

In the meantime you could use wildcard paths like:

```
**/testng-results.xml
```

so Jenkins will scan its WORKSPACE recursively looking for the `testng-results.xml` file in all available locations

Your `install` command also looks suspicious, normally you should not be putting your test artifacts to the [Maven repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) so you might want to use `mvn test` or `mvn verify` instead.

More information:

- [Turbo Boost Your Digital App Test Automation with Jenkins](https://experitest.com/continuous-integration-testing/jenkins_turbo_boost/)
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html